# The “module” configuration of TS config does not work?

Tags: javascript, typescript

index.ts

```
const m = require("./test");
console.log(m.a);
```

test.ts

```
module.exports = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};
```

After compilation

index.js

```
var m = require("./test");
console.log(m.a);
```

test.js

```
module.exports = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
```

The module specified in tsconfig.json is ES6. It should be compiled into a modular way such as `import {a} from 'test'`. Why is it still the modular way of commonjs?
[image]

Comment: What if you use a value later than ES6 like ES2022 or ESNext?

Comment: no!  It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can transpile ES6 (and TypeScript specific) module syntax into an arbitrary module syntax.

It cannot do it the other way round. Write modern code without `require` and `module.exports`.

Comment: So what does this configuration do?

Comment: You mean the `"module"` option in tsconfig? It determines the output type for modules written in TypeScript syntax (with `import` and `export`).

Comment: So it makes no sense to configure the value of "module" option as ES6?

Comment: Not if you're writing commonjs code.